# Random number Probability > 99%

Tags: probability

I need to write a unit test for a program. That program selects randomly a number between 1 and 3. I have a loop that runs n times to select a random number between 1 and 3 and then run the test for that number.

I want the probabilty that every number has at least been selected once to be greater than 99%. How can I calculate n?

Comment: So the probability that a specific number was never chosen after $n$ loops is $(2/3)^n$. Hence the probability that it was chosen at least once is $1-(2/3)^n$. Then solve.

Comment: So $1−(2/3)^n > 0.99$ I do not know how to transform the equation to get $n$ but trying yields $n = 12$ with the probability 0.9922... Is that correct?

Comment: You can solve it using logarithm :
\begin{align}
1-(2/3)^n > 0.99 \Leftrightarrow \\
(2/3)^n < 0.01 \Leftrightarrow \\
n\ln(2/3) < \ln(0.01)  \Leftrightarrow \\
n > \ln(0.01)/\ln(2/3) \approx 11.35
\end{align}
Hence you must have $n \geq 12$.